# Directional antenna in WSN

Tags: sensors, contiki

When using directional antenna in wireless sensor network, suppose there are two nodes, A and B. A and B will be able to transmit data only if both their beams intersect.

But my question is, will B be able to receive data from A, if B lies on the active sector of A but their beams don't intersect?

Comment: That would literary contradict the assumption described in the first sentence. It seems that you're the best person to answer this, since you know the model under which you're working, while we don't.

Comment: This question seems to out of the scope of this particular site, you should move this post to either the Electronics or DSP stack exchanges.